# LTE iPad needs to be connected to WiFi to choose data plan

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

I have an iPad with Apples eSIM. However, every time I want to choose a data plan, it:

- constantly tries to connect to the previous plan and fails. Every 5 seconds I am getting a message with "no network available
- if I click "choose a plan" it also says "no network available/not connected to a network"

It seems like I have to be connected to the Internet to choose a carrier? How absurd is this?

So I hotspotted my iPhone, connected my iPad and chose a new plan.

But that can't be right, can it? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: eSIM technology and network support is still in its infancy.

Comment: I think this is indeed "right". How could they verify your payment info without a network connection? This is the advantage to a physical device like a traditional sim card.

Comment: Well, why not establish a connection, for free, and send first my info over. This is ridiculous. Now I need WiFi to be able to create a network connection over eSIM.